# Parse Nested Json without KEY

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have this following json file

```
    {"Abra":[
    "Bangued",
    "Boliney",
    "Bucay",
    "Bucloc",
    "Daguioman",
    "Danglas"],

    "Agusan del Norte":[
    "Buenavista",
    "Butuan City",
    "Cabadbaran City",
    "Carmen",
    "Jabonga",
    "Kitcharao"]
    }
```

they represents municipalities in my country and inside them are the city they covered. My problem is that I don't know how to parse them in my code. The Municipalities are not static because it depends on the sender on whatever municipality he/she wants to send. Can anybody help me on what I should do.. I've been looking for solution all over the web but I did not find any success. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is converting this `JSONObject` into a `JSONArray` instead, such as following:

```
[
    "Abra":[
    "Bangued",
    "Boliney",
    "Bucay",
    "Bucloc",
    "Daguioman",
    "Danglas"],

    "Agusan del Norte":[
    "Buenavista",
    "Butuan City",
    "Cabadbaran City",
    "Carmen",
    "Jabonga",
    "Kitcharao"]
]
```

Then you can use the method `get()` of `JSONArray` allowing you to get the element at the specified position.

However the content of each element seems not to ne a valid JSON as it looks like an enum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already tried what you have stated, however I get an error indicating **Unterminated array at character 8**  Maybe its because the elements are not valid JSON.. as what you have said.. I really don't have an idea what's a valid json or not.. so thank you.. I will study on Json more and use another way in solving this problem.

Comment: A valid Json needs a key + its value. Here what you have looks like an enum ( see here http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html ). If you can, the best solution is to reformatting your json.

Comment: I agree, I guess I just have to give up on this format.. thank you.. i will take a look at your reference

Answer (score 1):

[keys()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys()) will return an iterator for the names in the JSON object. It can be used 
to cycle through the keys and retrieve the corresponding array.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("");
Iterator<String> iterator = json.keys();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    String key = iterator.next();
    JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray(key);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried this immediately after I read your answer however I encountered this error **Unterminated array at character 8** ..

Comment: If you have some problem with your json formatting, you could run it through a [json validator](http://jsonlint.com/). The json that you posted is valid, so I assume you're not using that.